# Node.js - Different authentication middleware and cors for different routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, cors

How do I apply a middleware only if it's matched by a route?

File `app.js`

```js
const routers = require('./routers');
app.use(routers);
```

File `routers/index.js`

```js
router.use('/first', firstRouter);
router.use('/second', secondRouter);
```

File `routers/first/index.js`

```js
router.use(cors(corsOptions));
router.use('/inner', innerRouter);
```

So I want to use `router.use(cors(corsOptions));` option only when `/first/*` is requested, how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example in the express [CORS guide](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html):

```js
router.use('/first', cors(corsOptions), firstRouter);
```

Generally speaking, you can chain multiple middleware this way, using an array:

```js
router.use('/first', [middle1, middle2, middle3], firstRouter);
```